# Como atribuir dados de um objeto a editText no Android?

Tags: android

Preciso atribuir em campos de EditText, do meu formulário, os dados de um objeto. Exemplo, estou usando uma API que busca endereço do usuário pelo viaCep. Já estou conseguindo retornar os dados, agora preciso jogar esse dados nos seus devidos campos.

```
public void getCEP(String cep){
  RequestParams rp = new RequestParams();

  AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
  client.get("http://viacep.com.br/ws/" + cep + "/json/", rp, new TextHttpResponseHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {
      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Problema na conexao!"+statusCode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString) {
      try {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(responseString);

        String retorno = "";

        if (!obj.has("erro")) {
          retorno += "\n" + obj.getString("cep");
          retorno += "\n" + obj.getString("logradouro");
          retorno += "\n" + obj.getString("complemento");
          retorno += "\n" + obj.getString("bairro");
          retorno += "\n" + obj.getString("localidade");
          retorno += "\n" + obj.getString("uf");
          retorno += "\n" + obj.getString("ibge");
          retorno += "\n" + obj.getString("gia");

          Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Dados retornados: "+retorno, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

          EditText edtCep = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtCep));
          //edtCep.setText("cep", retorno.);
        }

      } catch (JSONException e){

      }
    }
  });
}

public void btnCadastrar(View view) {

  final EditText edtNome = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtNome));
  final EditText edtSobrenome = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtSobrenome));
  EditText edtCelular = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtCelular));
  EditText edtCep = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtCep));

  final String nome = edtNome.getText().toString();
  String sobrenome = edtSobrenome.getText().toString();
  String celular = edtCelular.getText().toString();
  String cep = edtCep.getText().toString();

  String url = "http://reservacomdomanda.com/areaAdmin/api/area_admin/usuario.php";

  StringRequest srUrl = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {

    }
  }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

    }
  })
  {
    protected Map<String, String > getParams(){
      Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

      params.put("nome", edtNome.getText().toString());
      params.put("sobrenome", edtSobrenome.getText().toString());

      return params;
    }
  };

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No trecho que você deixou comentado, após declarar o EditText edtCep, basta trocar por esse comando:

```
edtCep.setText(obj.optString("cep"), TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
```

Comment: Certo, mas onde está o cep de dentro do objeto retorno, nesse seu comando? Tipo retorno.cep, algo assim

Comment: Usa "obj.getString("cep")" em vez de "retorno"

Comment: OK, vou tentar...

Comment: Se você não tem certeza que os dados de "obj" podem conter dados, usa optString em vez de getString, com isso o EditText vai simplesmente ficar vazio, em vez de gerar uma exceção.

Comment: Pois é, o que vc disse antes, não deu muito certo, pois dei um Lod.d... e retornou isso no console:
"D/CEP: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText{1b611dab VFED..CL ..."

Comment: Fiz isso:

edtCep.setText(obj.optString("cep"), TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
Log.d("CEP", String.valueOf(edtCep));

E não apareceu o cep no console

Comment: O cep pode não estar vindo no seu json. Na sua string "retorno" ele aparece?

Comment: Sim, tenho uma Toast que mostro os dados todos que vem no objeto retorno.
Aqui:
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Dados retornados: "+retorno, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: Sim, eu reparei esse toast. Mas é estranho o cep aparecer nele e não no editText, visto que ambos usam o mesmo obj.getString("cep").

Comment: Ta, esquece o que eu te disse antes kkkkk É que como eu já preencho o CEP pra buscar os dados, é óbvio que ele não vai reaparecer... Fiz o mesmo com logradouro e ele apareceu.... VALEU.

Answer (score 0):

Crie uma classe. Algo como:

```
public class Endereco {
    private String logradouro;

    public void setLogradouro(String logradouro) {
         this.logradouro = logradouro;
    }

    public String getLogradouro() {
        return logradouro;
    }
}
```

No retorno popule esse objeto

```
Endereco endereco = new Endereco();
endereco.setLogradouro(obj.getString("logradouro"));

edtCep.setText(endereco.getLogradouro());
```

Comment: Sim, até aí eu sei, mas e como pegar essa "alguma coisa" do objeto?

Comment: O setText para EditText precisa de um segundo parâmetro TextView.BufferType.

Comment: Criar uma classe só pra isso? É necessário?

Comment: Também acho que não.